# Transform a two-dimentional sparse result set with Ramdajs

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the following input:

```
var data = [{
      month: '2016-01',
      city: 'Paris',
      count: 6
    }, {
      month: '2016-01',
      city: 'London',
      count: 2
    }, {
      month: '2016-02',
      city: 'Paris',
      count: 15
    }, {
      month: '2016-03',
      city: 'London',
      count: 17
    }];
var cityList = ['Paris', 'London'];
```

The data is sparse because there can be months without all cities, and cities without all months.

I want to transform this hash in the following format:

```
rowsByCity = [{
  city: 'Paris',
  counts: [6, 15, null]
}, {
  city: 'London',
  counts: [2, null, 17]
}];
```

How can I do that with Ramdajs ([docs](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#)) ? (I don't mind a pure js solution if it is simple)

Ideally, I would like to avoid pre-populating empty months counts with [null, null, null] and merging into it. Maybe by directly using a transformation on the data (transpose?). But I'm not sure how to do it, or if it is possible.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtr0js55/

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not beautiful, and it's also not very efficient, but here's something that I think will work:

```
const extract = R.converge(
  (data, cities, months) => R.map(city => ({
    city,
    counts: R.map(month => (
      R.find(record => record.city === city && 
                       record.month === month, data) || 
      {count: null}
    ).count, months)
  }), cities), [
  R.identity,
  R.compose(uniq, pluck('city')),
  R.compose(uniq, pluck('month'))
]);

extract(data);
```

Comment: I think this is slightly cooler than my version. Also I didn't know about converge. +1

Comment: Converge is useful when you really want to make something points-free.  Ramda also has a somewhat related function, [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), that can occasionally be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, but it involves merging into a pre-populated months list.

I'm sure this can be made simpler

```
var months = R.uniq(R.pluck('month', data));
var defaultMonths = R.zipObj(months, R.repeat(null, months.length));
var result = R.mapObjIndexed(
  function(counts, city) {
    return {
      city: city,
      counts: R.values(R.merge(
        defaultMonths,
        R.mapObjIndexed(R.prop('count'), R.indexBy(R.prop('month'), counts))
      ))
    };
  },
  R.groupBy(R.prop('city'), data))
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/s141r74y/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using xprod:

```
var months = R.uniq(R.pluck('month', data));
var cities = R.uniq(R.pluck('city', data));
var result = R.values(R.mapObjIndexed(
  (array, city) => {
    return {
      city: city,
      counts: array.map((attrs) => {
        return R.find((record) => {
          return record.city === attrs[0] && record.month === attrs[1];
        }, data)
      }).map(R.path(['count']))
    }
  },
  R.groupBy(R.prop(0), R.xprod(cities, months))));

console.log(result)
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/44ysat8d/